# How to Join a query to another query

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have two queries, and I want to join the first query with the second in SQL, here are my queries,

FIRST QUERY

```
OleDbCommand Query1 = new OleDbCommand();
Query.CommandText = "SELECT [Mastertable].ID " +
"FROM [Mastertable] INNER JOIN [relationship] ON [Mastertable].ID = [relationship].SW1_ID " +
"WHERE ([Mastertable].[PN]= @PN AND [Mastertable].[Ver]=@Ver) " +
"GROUP BY [Mastertable].[ID]";

DataSet ResultSet = RunQuery(Query1);
```

The above query basic return the ID where PN = PN input and Ver = Version input.( I put the result in a Dataset

I want to join the ID column from query1 to Mastertable. ID again

the 2nd query,

```
OleDbCommand Query2 = new OleDbCommand();
Query2.CommandText = "SELECT [Mastertable].PN, [Mastertable].[Ver], [relationship].[Category], [Mastertable].[Component_Name] " +
"FROM (Query1 INNER JOIN [relationship] ON Query1.[ID] = [relationship].SID) INNER JOIN " +
"[Mastertable] ON [relationship].SW2_ID = [Mastertable].[ID]";

DataSet ResultSet2 = RunQuery(Query2);
```

but this code doesn't work, I searched on the web alot and tried a few, but they didn't help. I was thinking to use the ResultSet1.Tables[0].TableName and ResultSet1.Tables[0].Columns[0].Name, but that didn't work =(

Please help

Comment: I think is better use just one query. SQL is the best place to join data.

Comment: SOLVE! THANKS EVERYONE! =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OleDbCommand Query2 = new OleDbCommand();
Query2.CommandText = "SELECT [SW Mastertable].SW_PN, [SW Mastertable].[SW_Ver], [SW relationship].[SW2_Category]," + 
" [SW Mastertable].[Component_Name] " +
" FROM " +
"(SELECT [Mastertable].ID as ID " +
"FROM [Mastertable] INNER JOIN [relationship] ON [Mastertable].ID = [relationship].SW1_ID " +
"WHERE ([Mastertable].[PN]= @PN AND [Mastertable].[Ver]=@Ver) " +
"GROUP BY [Mastertable].[ID]) as Query1 " +
" INNER JOIN [SW relationship] ON Query1.[ID] = [SW relationship].SW1_ID INNER JOIN " +
"[SW Mastertable] ON [SW relationship].SW2_ID = [SW Mastertable].[ID]";

DataSet ResultSet2 = RunQuery(Query2);
```

Comment: YES! THANK you so much! IT worked. Thanks for showing me how to use AS Query1

Answer (score 1):

You can join Query1 to the second (outer) Query2 as a derived table as follows:

```
SELECT [SW Mastertable].SW_PN, [SW Mastertable].[SW_Ver], 
       [SW relationship].[SW2_Category], [SW Mastertable].[Component_Name]
FROM 
  (SELECT [Mastertable].ID
    FROM [Mastertable] 
      INNER JOIN [relationship] ON [Mastertable].ID = [relationship].SW1_ID
    WHERE ([Mastertable].[PN]= @PN AND [Mastertable].[Ver]=@Ver)
    GROUP BY [Mastertable].[ID]
  ) Query1
  INNER JOIN [SW relationship] ON Query1.[ID] = [SW relationship].SW1_ID) 
  INNER JOIN [SW Mastertable] ON [SW relationship].SW2_ID = [SW Mastertable].[ID];
```

If you are using `sql-server` you can also do this with a CTE:

```
WITH Query1 AS
(
  SELECT [Mastertable].ID
    FROM [Mastertable] 
        INNER JOIN [relationship] ON [Mastertable].ID = [relationship].SW1_ID
    WHERE ([Mastertable].[PN]= @PN AND [Mastertable].[Ver]=@Ver)
    GROUP BY [Mastertable].[ID]
)
SELECT [SW Mastertable].SW_PN, [SW Mastertable].[SW_Ver], 
       [SW relationship].[SW2_Category], [SW Mastertable].[Component_Name]
FROM 
  Query1
    INNER JOIN [SW relationship] ON Query1.[ID] = [SW relationship].SW1_ID) 
    INNER JOIN [SW Mastertable] ON [SW relationship].SW2_ID = [SW Mastertable].[ID];
```

Comment: This is SQL. The op is using asp.net

Comment: OP clearly states `join the first query with the second in SQL`

Comment: I added "AS Query1 INNER JOIN [SW Relation]" instead of just "Query1 INNER JOIN [SW Relation]" and it worked! Thanks

Comment: The `AS` keyword is [indicated as optional](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) on BOL inter-alia, on derived tables.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure if this will work but still you can try it out. Also please fix the syntax errors if any.

Also I am assuming that you have the Query1 object available (i.e. not null or not out of scope) while trying to create Query2 object.

```
OleDbCommand Query2 = new OleDbCommand();
Query2.CommandText = "SELECT [SW Mastertable].SW_PN, [SW Mastertable].[SW_Ver], [SW relationship].[SW2_Category], [SW Mastertable].[Component_Name], [SW relationship].SW2_ID " +
"FROM (("+ Query1.CommandText +")TAB1 INNER JOIN [SW relationship] ON TAB1.[ID] = [SW relationship].SW1_ID) TAB2 INNER JOIN " +
"[SW Mastertable] ON [TAB2].SW2_ID = [SW Mastertable].[ID]";

DataSet ResultSet2 = RunQuery(Query2);
```

Hope this helps.